# The item with the specified name wasn't found

Tags: vba, excel

Hello and thank you in advance.

To be honest I have no idea what is wrong in this scenario. I have used this function before, multiple times, to great effect; however, this time it throws an error.

```
Function CountUnique(ByVal Rng As Range) As Long
  Dim St As String
  Set Rng = Intersect(Rng, Rng.Parent.UsedRange)
  St = "'" & Rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & Rng.Address(False, False)
  CountUnique = Evaluate("SUM(IF(LEN(" & St & "),1/COUNTIF(" & St & "," & St & ")))") 'ERROR HERE
End Function
```

The error is on the last line where I am returning the result back. I used this function earlier in my code and the same error popped up. I scanned through the code, nothing seemed wrong so I pressed continue on the debug and it went through (literally no change was made).

Edit 1:
I used it in this manner:

```
lTotal = CountUnique(wSht.UsedRange.Columns(1))
```

I am trying to count up the number unique part numbers within that column.

Comment: it seems that your range contains error values like `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#DIV/0!` and so on

Comment: Updated the question to add a bit more context. Do you have any suggestions that may help me correct this?

Comment: what error have you got? `Type Missmatch`?

Comment: Error is in the title: "The item with the specified name wasn't found" highlighting the marked line

Comment: What is the value of `St`? Can you `debug.print St` after `St = "'" & Rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & Rng.Address(False, False)` and see what does it give?

Comment: The value of St at this point is: "'Original On Hand'!D1:D35263"
"original on hand" is the name of the worksheet going in, and that range is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, ended up using a different function. I couldn't find where the issue was, regardless of what I changed.
Here is the one I used:

```
Public Function CntUnique(rng As Range)
Dim Uni As Collection, cl As Range, LpRange As Range
Dim clswfrm As Range, clswcst As Range, myRng As Range
Dim TotUni As Long
'*************
Set myRng = rng 'define your sheet/range
'*************
On Error Resume Next
Set clswfrm = myRng.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
Set clswcst = myRng.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set myRng = Nothing 'free up memory
On Error GoTo 0
If clswfrm Is Nothing And clswcst Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No Unique Cells"
    Exit Function
    ElseIf Not clswfrm Is Nothing And Not clswcst Is Nothing Then
        Set LpRange = Union(clswcst, clswfrm)
    ElseIf clswfrm Is Nothing Then Set LpRange = clswcst
    Else: Set LpRange = clswfrm
End If
Set clswfrm = Nothing: Set clswcst = Nothing 'Free up memory
Set Uni = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For Each cl In LpRange
    Uni.Add cl.Value, CStr(cl.Value) 'assign unique key string
Next cl
On Error GoTo 0
Set LpRange = Nothing 'free up memory
TotUni = Uni.Count
Set Uni = Nothing ''free up memory
CntUnique = TotUni 'Work with the Unique value total here (replace msgbox)
End Function
```